# Widgets lead to DeadObjectException - Transaction failed on small parcel

Tags: android, widget

I'm getting following exception as soon as I want to show a widget and start listening:

```
// the relevant stack trace, the rest is comming from my code 
// before the code line I posted below
java.lang.RuntimeException: system server dead?
    at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.startListening(AppWidgetHost.java:189)
    at com.my.app.utils.WidgetUtil.a(SourceFile:231)
    ...
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
    at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.startListening(IAppWidgetService.java:481)
    at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.startListening(AppWidgetHost.java:185)
    at com.my.app.utils.WidgetUtil.a(SourceFile:231)
    ...
```

The source in my code is following code line:

```
 mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
 mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(context, R.string.app_name);
 mAppWidgetHost.startListening(); // <= this line leads to the crash
```

**Observations**

- my app is working normally on a lot of phones (all but one actually)
- above crash only happens on one users device (SM-N910C (Samsung Note 4), Android 6.0.1)
- the user says, those widgets work fine in his launcher

Does anyone has an idea what could cause this? Is this something I can solve in my app? The user says widgets are working fine in his launcher...

Answer (score 4):

So, a simple Google search led me to this definition of a [DeadObjectException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html) :-

> The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.

From this, it is obvious that you're getting this error because the process that's hosting `mAppWidgetHost` has been killed off.

The question now is that why are you getting this error. Overriding and logging `onDestroy()` to monitor it could be useful, and definitely is worth a shot. But, since its working on all devices except for one, its more than likely that there's nothing wrong with the `onDestroy()` method. Instead, the OS is killing the process off before you can access the object.

So, now why is the OS doing that? This question had me balled up for the longest time. I still do not have a clear answer or solution to this despite a bevy of Google searches with all kinds of related to the problem. But, after spending a considerable amount of time searching, I noticed a peculiarity - most of the issues with this exception, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418357/appwidgethost-crash-android-os-transactiontoolargeexception), [this](https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk/issues/266) and yours happen with Samsung devices.

My guess is that Samsung's underlying architecture leads to this problem. And, while I do not have a reason why this happens or a plausible solution even after a lot more searching, this could still be a start to find a work around targeting Samsung devices.

**UPDATE**

I searched a bit more and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314489/android-activity-crash-deadobjectexception) answer. Take a look at the last comment by the question author on the question :-

> Finally it is working fine just by a line of code in manifest file, here it is `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` If anybody get the following kind of errors please try by adding the above line signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

I don't know the logic behind this or if it would work or not. Just sharing it with the hope that it could help you - even in the minutest form.

Comment: Again, how should I do this? Widgets are provided by other apps, all my app does is in my code example, I only tell another app "I display the widget with ID so please inform me whenever this widget needs to be updated" and this registration instantly crashes on the specified device...

Comment: Additional info: I know that it's working on samsung s6, s7 and s8, so it may be some device specific issue with the note 4, but I've no idea yet why it crashes in my app but not in the default launcher...

Comment: Did you try the hardwareaccelarated = false method that seemed to work for someone else?

Answer (score 0):

```
DeadObjectException :
```

The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.

**Possible Solutions:**

1) Override your service's `onDestroy()` method and watch what event flow leads to it. If you catch `DeadObjectException` without going through this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.

2) by removing `Typeface` , this might be because of ttf which i was using from assets folder Please try comment the typeface and test it hope it will work for sure

3) put all your code inside the `onCreate`. From there you will see what is the culprit like a `NullPointerException` for example but your code will run smoothly already.

Comment: You know that widgets are implemented by other apps and I'm only telling the other app "I display the widget with ID so please inform me whenever this widget needs to be updated". So how should I intercept other apps code?